# How to declare ID as number in Typescript?

Tags: asp.net, typescript

I have been trying to use type number for the id of one of my entities and I get this error in typescript -

Type '{ id: number; }' does not satisfy the constraint '{ id?: string | undefined; }'.
Types of property 'id' are incompatible.
Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string | undefined'.

I tried using Guid at first, but when I wanted to upload files to my entity, for some reason type Guid was throwing errors, and wasn't compatible with my SaveFile method. Is this fixable?

Thank you in advance! :)

Comment: You have some type defined as `id?: string | undefined` but you're trying to assign `id: number` to it. You have to correct that type but without any knowledge of how and where it's defined, it's almost impossible to give you concrete suggestion.

Comment: I think it has to do with typescript, as I read somewhere that the latest update requires string for ID. I made sure I changed all the declarations to number, but the error still persists.

Comment: TypeScript uses the types it is provided. It does not change them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The library you’re using is expecting the “id” to be a string, so you should just convert your number to string. As VLAZ mentioned in the comment, there’s no problem with the typescript, so it depends on you to adapt to it.

let idNumber = 5264;
const obj = { id: idNumber.toString()  };